# Visualize a graph in matlab

Tags: matlab, graph

I have a graph consisting of a set of edges with their corresponding start and end nodes. These were generated for a specific region of a city. How can I visualize this graph in matlab

Answer (score 8):

Check out this function:

> doc gplot

Example:

```
% Plot half of a "Bucky ball" carbon molecule, placing asterisks at each node:
k = 1:30;
[B,XY] = bucky;
gplot(B(k,k),XY(k,:),'-*')
axis square
```

[image: gplot_output]

Comment: +1, ditto. A practical example or a bit more juice in the answer would have not been bad, though.

Comment: Most graphs don't have coordinates from the start, matlab-bgl includes a few useful layout algorithms, `gplot(A, fruchterman_reingold_force_directed_layout(A));`