# How to graph a connectivity/adjacency matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, adjacency-matrix

I want to graph the structure of a network (a power grid) in MATLAB. I have a list containing to-from nodes for each branch. I don't have coordinates for the nodes, and the system topology changes for every simulation.

I also need to be able to assign different colors to various lines / nodes, to visualize voltage issues or overloads etc, similar to what I've done using biograph (code below).

The BIOGRAPH function is almost perfect. The drawback is that the lines always go out the "bottom" of the ancestor block, and into the "top" of the descendant. As an ancestor is always displayed above its descendants, the graphs are sometimes very chaotic (for large systems).

I have tried changing the property 'LayoutType' of the biograph from the default  'hierarchical' to both 'radial' and 'equilibrium', but this gives even worse results.

Is what I'm asking possible? It doesn't need to be a perfect solution, any improvements would be great.

This is the code I use now:

```
%% Plot biograph
Sys = sparse(from,to,1,s,s);  

SysTri = tril(Sys + Sys'); 
bg = biograph(SysTri,[],'ShowArrows','off','ShowWeights','off');
h = view(bg);  

 %% Color faulted line:
set(h.nodes(newFaultNodes),'Color',[1 0.4 0.4]);
fowEdges = getedgesbynodeid(h,get(h.Nodes(newFaultNodes),'ID'));
revEdges = getedgesbynodeid(h,get(h.Nodes(fliplr(newFaultNodes)),'ID'));
edges = [fowEdges;revEdges];
set(edges,'LineColor',[1 0 0])
set(edges,'LineWidth',2)
```

Comment: You could try out [grphviz4matlab](http://code.google.com/p/graphviz4matlab/)

Comment: It looks like grphvis4matlab could work well. The problem is I can't get it to work. I have installed graphviz-2.30.1, and tried to follow the descriptions on the web-site. The Matlab functions works, but they can't find the graphviz-programs. I get messages like:
'neato' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file. Please install or upgrade graphViz. 

I believe I have the files in the correct folders, and I have tried re-installing graphViz. 

Thanks anyway =)

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037499/visualize-a-graph-in-matlab)

Comment: @user1666357: Late reply: I have looked at the `gplot` function earlier. My problem is that I don't have any coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Try out [matlab-bgl](https://github.com/dgleich/matlab-bgl). It links to the Boost Graph library and includes a few useful layout algorithms. You can then use `gplot` to visualize.

```
gplot(A, fruchterman_reingold_force_directed_layout(A));
```